# Ignore ${project.version} in Maven release:prepare

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

We have projects that are built one after another in the build server. They probably could become a multi-module project in the future, but at the moment there is no capacity for restructuring the repositories, projects etc. and introducing new parent POMs.

We tried to use a structure like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.something</groupId>
  <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.something</groupId>
      <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Unfortunately, the maven release plugin (more specifically, the `release:prepare` goal) fails on this because it considers the dependency to be a SNAPSHOT dependency.

Is there any way (besides rebuilding everything as multi-module) to tell the maven release plugin that this is not the case?

Something like

- "`${project.version}` is ok, don't worry"
- or "Don't check project2 for SNAPSHOT"

Comment: An alternative could be to get rid of the Maven's release functionality alltogether and instead utilize on a `${revision}` property that can later on be set with `-Drevision=3.2.1` by the build pipeline. This requires the usage of the flatten plugin to actually resolve the version in the pom and allow the up- and download of the artifacts by Maven. [This blog post](https://medium.com/outbrain-engineering/faster-release-with-maven-ci-friendly-versions-and-a-customised-flatten-plugin-fe53f0fcc0df) sums up the process and even provides a faster alternative to the flatten-plugin

Comment: My assumption is that project2 version is not 9.0.2-SNAPSHOT? I assume that the version is something like "X.X.X" (but not SNAPSHOT). So I would suggest to put the literal version without SNAPSHOT into it..

Comment: @khmarbaise the thing is: Several projects should be build with the same version (like in a multi-module project), so we need a property.

Comment: I have understood and expected exactly that requirement but if you keep the property the release plugin will check that and will fail... a dependency during a release is not allowed to be a snapshot which is not part of the reactor which here is exactly the case. So you have to go first and release project2 and afterwards you can release project1 unfortunately I don't see any other option except to restructure into a multi module which you have already mentioned that's not possible at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "solution" is as follows:

- define a property `<dep.version>${project.version}</dep.version>` in the POM and use it instead of `${project.version}`.
- Use the versions maven plugin to update the property `${dep.version}` before the build to the next release version (and commit).
- Do the build
- Run the version plugin to reset the value `${dep.version}` back to `${project.version}`.

Answer (score 0):

Hardcode the version.  In your example, use `9.0.2-SNAPSHOT` instead of `${project.version}`.  Maven understands that the reactor and the dependency are in the same project and have the same version, so the `maven-release-plugin` will update both versions to `9.0.2` for the release and `9.0.3-SNAPSHOT` for the next snapshot by default — nothing else required.